# Export a grid in safari

Tags: angular

Am using excel export to export a grid. It is working fine in chrome but not exporting in safari. No errors are being logged in the console. All the data are coming till the end properly but only exporting to excel is not happening.

```
 <kendo-excelexport [data]="exportingData" [fileName]="fileName" #excelexport>
     <kendo-excelexport-column field="packagenumber" title="Package #">
     </kendo-excelexport-column>
     <kendo-excelexport-column field="itemname" title="Package Name">
     </kendo-excelexport-column>
</kendo-excelexport>


    const options = excelExport.workbookOptions();
    const rows = options.sheets[0].rows;
    options.sheets[0].name = fileName;
    excelExport.save(options);
```

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example